# How do i get an if/else statement to run if it's not true or false?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what i did:

```
    var yes = true;
    var no = false;

    function run() {

         if(yes === no) {
                console.log("wait...");
         } else if (yes !== no) {
                console.log("wait a minute...");
         } else {
                console.log("Starting...");
         }

   }

   run(); // case 2 to run = correct
```

So if i run this code... the second else will run right?

if i add this:

```
    function change() {
         yes = false;
    }

    change(); // case 1 to run = correct
```

Now that both "yes" and "no" are equal... the code for "if" will run right?

But now: How would i go about creating something that is "not not equal"? Wouldn't it just be "equal"? if so... case 1 runs but not case 3. And if it's just not equal... case 2 runs. How do i get case 3 to run and console log "starting..."?

Comment: Uh, yeah... It should run.

Comment: case 3 wont happen though.

Comment: you need to make it explicitly clear *what* you are asking here

Comment: case 3 won't run in this case because case 1 and 2 cover every scenario

Comment: so there is no grey area?

Comment: `Comparison and Logical operators are used to test for true or false.` (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)) - and you'd like to introduce a third boolean state?

Comment: Why you asign for no false and for yes true, you can simply use true and false because it is constant. You don't have to write if(x == true) it is enaugh if (x) and if (!x). Keep it simple, than such questions are obvious.

Comment: @SethVillamil it's unclear what you're asking. Are `yes` and `no` meant to be input of some sort? Is it possible that they would have values other than `true` or `false`, such as `null`?

Comment: @zzzzBov In general: I wanna know how to get the last "else' to run. How do i make a condition that is either false or true?

Comment: btw. the cool thing about boolean values is, they just can be just true or false... so setting yes to true or false = doesn't make any logical sense ;)  i think by using a more intelligent naming u will not run into these kinda logic issues ;)

Comment: Perhaps if yes was a string, like `yes = "true";` then the first check (`"true" === true`) would be false and the second check (`"true" === false`) would also be false. But surely you would have told us if that was the case.

Comment: @ippi that makes sense. im gonna give it a shot.

Comment: @ippi to verify i also made it "not a string". And also doing what you said and making it a string still ran case 2  sadly. :/

Comment: @SethVillamil "How do I make a condition that is either false or true?" all conditions are either false or true, that's how conditionals work. Do you mean to ask how you can have a *value* that is *neither* `false` *nor* `true`?

Comment: Woops sorry... @zzzzBov i meant *neither*. And yes, i want to make a grey area.

Comment: you can set up an if statement along the lines of `if (input === true) {...} else if (input === false) {...} else {...}` if you want to handle boolean values separate from non-boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the third condition to run with the code you have, and while also creating a *not not equal* situation; you'll need to change your second condition to represent a **falsy** statement like so:

```
else if(!yes !== no) { // this is **not** `yes` **not** equal to `no`
// use your imagination to find other not not combinations.
```

Otherwise your second condition will always be **truthy** and will prevent `starting...` from logging into the console.

Comment: Ha ha... This one is hilarious.

Comment: Why would you flip the value of a bool when you could just put the statement outside of the `if`?

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he wanted to create a **not not** condition, which is why I flipped the bool value. I tried to stay as close to the implementation as possible as well

Comment: Which is correct, i want a "not not equal" condition

Comment: @AGE i tried what you posted and changed the line of code where: (yes !== no) to (!yes !== no). I got the console to log starting! But now im unsure how to get it to say "wait a minute..." Do i actually make the second line changes? Or do i make an entirely new else if after that line and just before the last else statement?

Comment: There's a shock, bad code does bad things.

Comment: @JayGould agreed, but curiosity knows no bounds ;)

Comment: @AGE while I don't disagree, this answer is giving me a facial tick from stress :)

Comment: @JayGould specificity is in the eye of the beholder, in this case the OP's :) and lol to your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
var yes = true;
var no = false;

if(yes === no) {
    console.log('yes!')
} else if(yes !== no) {
    console.log('hang on a second..')
}

console.log('starting');
```

Your above code in the question is saying this:

1. If `yes` is equal to `no`, log `wait...`.
2. If `yes` does not equal no, log `wait a minute...`
3. If **both of those conditions fail**, log `starting....`

If you want `starting...` to always log regardless of *which* condition is met, simply place it after, and outside of, the if statement.

Comment: Im still new to java script would my if/else syntax still be correct even without "else" at the end?

Comment: Yes, it'll be correct. Your statement in your question is technically **3** conditions, whereas I believe you only want 2 and then to log `starting...` regardless of whether `yes === no` or not.

Comment: Im trying to create an "not not equal condition". While what you say makes sense, it doesn't answer my question.